# How to define individual service name for each type of Opentelemetry auto instrumentation in a python application?

Tags: django, instrumentation, datadog, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

We are currently using Datadog for monitoring and observability in our application, and we have integrated OpenTelemetry for distributed tracing.

We have encountered one main issue

Span Separation: Currently, all the spans from our application are being exported to Datadog under a single service. However, we would like to separate them into different services based on the type of instrumentation used (e.g., Django, Elasticsearch, requests, etc.).

Manage.py

```
configure_opentelemetry()
    #Auto Instrumentation of Django, Psycopg2, Pymemcache, Elasticsearch, URLLib3, Requests
    DjangoInstrumentor().instrument(request_hook=fix_django_req)
    PymemcacheInstrumentor().instrument()
    RequestsInstrumentor().instrument()
    ElasticsearchInstrumentor().instrument()
    Psycopg2Instrumentor().instrument(enable_commenter=True, commenter_options={})
    URLLib3Instrumentor().instrument()
```

configure_opentelemetry method

```
def configure_opentelemetry():
    
    otlp_exporter = OTLPSpanExporter(endpoint=os.getenv("OTEL_COLLECTOR_URL"), insecure=True)

    # Set the global TracerProvider with the OTLP exporter
    trace.set_tracer_provider(TracerProvider(resource=Resource.create({SERVICE_NAME: os.getenv("OTEL_SERVICE_NAME"), "env": os.getenv('OTEL_ENV')})))

    # Create a BatchSpanProcessor and add the exporter to it
    span_processor = BatchSpanProcessor(otlp_exporter)
    
    trace.get_tracer_provider().add_span_processor(span_processor)

    tracer = trace.get_tracer(__name__)
```

Collector Config:

```
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
      http:

processors:
  batch:
    # batch metrics before sending to reduce API usage
    send_batch_max_size: 100
    send_batch_size: 10
    timeout: 10s

  memory_limiter:
    # drop metrics if memory usage gets too high
    check_interval: 1s
    limit_percentage: 65
    spike_limit_percentage: 20

  resourcedetection:
    detectors: [env, gcp]
    timeout: 2s
    override: false

  transform:
    error_mode: ignore
    trace_statements:
      - context: span
        statements:
          - set(attributes["resource.name"], name)

exporters:
  datadog:
    api:
      site: ${DD_SITE}
      key: ${DD_API_KEY}

extensions:
  health_check:

service:

  extensions: [health_check]
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [memory_limiter, resourcedetection, batch, transform]
      exporters: [datadog]
    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [memory_limiter, resourcedetection, batch]
      exporters: [datadog]
      
  telemetry:
    logs:
      level: "debug"
```

Please help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The OpenTelemetry SDK libraries are designed to be used under one service, hence a single `service.name` exists within the resource, it is immutable and it is shared across all instrumentation libraries that you use. Usually, backends use this service.name to identify telemetry originating from a single source, and telemetry can be correlated together under one umbrella.

If your goal is to uniquely identify what telemetry originates from which instrumentation, the `service.name` is not the place to do it. Ideally, you should use span attributes specifying which instrumentation created that specific span/piece of telemetry. Datadog should have a way of displaying and filtering by span attributes. You can access the name of the instrumentation that generated the span by the `InstrumentationScope` property and use a custom span processor to add this field as a span attribute to every span you send out as a piece of telemetry.

```py
class CustomSpanProcessor(BatchSpanProcessor):
    def on_end(self, span: ReadableSpan) -> None:
         span.set_attribute("instrumentation_name", span.instrumentation_scope.name)
         super().on_end(span)

...
span_processor = CustomSpanProcessor(otlp_exporter)
trace.get_tracer_provider().add_span_processor(span_processor)
```

Comment: I tried it but I am getting the below error:
AttributeError: 'ReadableSpan' object has no attribute 'set_attribute'

Seems like set_attribute it is not accessible with the ReadableSpan

Comment: Apologies. You can use `on_start` which looks like `def on_start(self, span: Span, parent_context = None)` instead.

Comment: class CustomSpanProcessor(BatchSpanProcessor):
    def on_start(self, span: Span, parent_context = None):
        span.set_attribute("service.name", (span.instrumentation_scope.name).split(".")[2])

I was able to set using the onstart method. but it creates duplicate spans at times for few instrumentations 

Whatever attirbutes I add (either "instrumentation_name" or "service.name") it creates a duplicate traces at times for few instrumentations.

Comment: The new custom span processor should not be related to sending multiple spans, are you sure this did not occur before? I would also suggest creating an issue in the github repo as this most likely requires more investigation. https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-python/issues/new/choose